# SoundCloud Player Widget start autoplay after onMediaDoneBuffering

Tags: soundcloud

I got a big problem. The SoundCloud Widget (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget) starts the autoplay primal when onMediaDoneBuffering is fired. I want that autoplay works directly on onPlayerReady, like in documentation.

This problem appear mostly on Mac. Someone got a solution?

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the player first needs to buffer parts of the audio before it can play it back. The onPlayerReady event is only fired to inform that the player is fully initialized.

Can't you change your code to wait until the onMediaDoneBuffering was fired?